# Excel VBA refresh internet explorer page

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that takes HTML data from a website and puts it into excel. There are about 100 webpages that it navigates to and sometimes it gets stuck, or ends up using so much memory that I need to close IE and start again. The refreshing of internet explorer is held in another sub routine. The problem I want answered is how to check if the script has lost the ie object. I can't use `If Not (ie Is Nothing) Then` because ie exists, but there are no variables. If I try `ie.Count` I just receive an error. Here is the code in full (the ie object is declared in the main code):

```
Sub refresh_Page(ie, ByVal websiteName As String, numTries)

numTries = numTries + 1
If Not (ie Is Nothing) Then
    If Not (ie.Count = 0) Then
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    End If
End If

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"))
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate websiteName
iSecondCounter = 0
'Wait until the website has loaded
Do While ie.Busy And iSecondCounter < 30
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
iSecondCounter = iSecondCounter + 1
Loop

If iSecondCounter = 30 And numTries <= 3 Then
    Call refresh_Page(ie, websiteName, numTries)
    ElseIf numTries = 3 Then
    MsgBox "Error with " & websiteName & " exiting code"
    Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Main Code:

```
Sub Refresh_data()

Dim ie, dataListCum As Object
Dim websiteName As String
Dim startTimem, SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim numRows, numCols As Long
Dim cumulativeItem() As String
Dim lenArray, numTries As Integer
Dim underlying() As Variant
Dim FI, UM As Worksheet

'Start timer
startTime = Timer

'Open internet explorer
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'ie.Visible = True

'Stop excel automatically calculating and updating the sheet each loop
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Set up the underlying markets data to be written into excel later
Set FI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("fund_info")
Set UM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("underlying_markets")

numRows = UM.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
numCols = UM.Range("A1:AA1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count + 1

ReDim underlying(numRows, numCols)

For i = 1 To numRows
underlying(i, 1) = UM.Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value
Next i

For rowNum = 2 To 124
'Refresh Internet explorer every 10 goes
numTries = 0
If rowNum Mod 10 = 0 Then
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    End If

websiteName = FI.Range("G" & rowNum).Value

'In a few instances I couldn't get trustnet data - I'll work on those later
If Mid(websiteName, 13, 8) = "trustnet" Then
    ie.navigate websiteName

On Error Resume Next

    iSecondCounter = 0
    'Wait until the website has loaded
    Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    iSecondCounter = iSecondCounter + 1
     'If the page is taking too long to load then refresh the page
        If iSecondCounter > 30 Then Call refresh_Page(ie, websiteName, numTries)
    Loop

    'Give it a few seconds to fully load - this website is problematic
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:13"))

    'Scrape the data using HTML search
    Set dataListCum = ie.Document.querySelectorAll("performance-table table td")

    'Sometimes the data doesn't come in, so refresh the page and try again
    While dataListCum.Length = 0 Or IsNull(dataListCum.Item(1))
        Call refresh_Page(ie, websiteName, numTries)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:13"))
        Set dataListCum = ie.Document.querySelectorAll("performance-table table td")
        Wend


    'Collect the data
    lenArray = dataListCum.Length
    ReDim cumulativeItem(lenArray)
    'Write the data into excel
    For i = 1 To lenArray - 1
        cumulativeItem(i) = dataListCum.Item(i).innerText
        Next i

    'Need to check if underlying market data has already been created
    Dim Market As String

    Market = FI.Range("M" & rowNum).Value

    For i = 1 To numCols
        If underlying(i, 1) = Market Then
            If IsEmpty(underlying(i, 2)) Then
            updateMarket = 1
            Exit For
            Else
            updateMarket = 0
            Exit For
            End If
        End If
        Next i



    Debug.Print rowNum

    'Write the data into excel
    For i = 1 To 5
        Select Case lenArray 'Sometimes there is no underlying market to compare against

        Case 36
        Debug.Print cumulativeItem(i); " / "; cumulativeItem(i + 24)
        FI.Range("N" & rowNum).Offset(0, i - 1).Value = cumulativeItem(i)
        FI.Range("S" & rowNum).Offset(0, i - 1).Value = cumulativeItem(i + 24)
        'If we need to update the underlying market data
        If updateMarket = 1 Then
            For j = 1 To numCols
                If underlying(j, 1) = Market Then
                    For k = 1 To 5
                        underlying(j, k + 1) = cumulativeItem(i + 6)
                        underlying(j, k + 6) = cumulativeItem(i + 30)
                        Next k
                    End If
                Next j
            End If

        Case 12
        Debug.Print cumulativeItem(i); " / "; cumulativeItem(i + 6)
        FI.Range("N" & rowNum).Offset(0, i - 1).Value = cumulativeItem(i)
        FI.Range("S" & rowNum).Offset(0, i - 1).Value = cumulativeItem(i + 6)
        End Select
        Next i

End If
Next rowNum

'Close internet explorer
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

'Write the underlying market data to excel
UM.Range("A2:K20").Value = underlying()

'Turn on automatic calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'Stop timer
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - startTime, 2)
MsgBox "This code took " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm presuming that this UDF is being called within a loop in your `main code`? If so, are you creating a new IE object each time in your code? Also, try `IsObject`along side `If Not (ie Is Nothing) Then`

Comment: @Zac - I'm not creating a new object every loop in the main function. I create one at the start then navigate to a new page each loop. How would I include `IsObject` in the line? Something like `If IsObject(ie) And Not (ie Is Nothing) Then`

Edit: I've just tried `IsObject` and it is returning that ie is an object.

Comment: Sounds like issue might be in your main function. It might be that you are creating too many IE objects (which would indicate why you are running out of memory as well). Can you post your main function? (or atleast the part where this UDF is being called in the loop). You probably don't need to include `Not (ie Is Nothing)`. Try just: `If IsObject(ie) Then`. Although, as I said, I think the issue is in your main function

Comment: I've posted the main code. I've screwed up with the writing of the underlying variant array, but I'm not too worried about that at this stage.

Comment: Might be a silly question but did you try `ie.Refresh` instead of your `refresh_page` UDF? Also, not sure why you have to keep destroying the `ie` object? you can use the same object and just refresh the page. Everytime you create a new 'ie' object, you are using more of your memory

Comment: You may check if IE is lost `If TypeName(IE) = "Object" Then MsgBox "IE lost"`. Why not just use XHR instead of laggard IE?